# Inflection and maximum growth rate Logistic Curve

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the inflection point and the point of maximum slope of a logistic curve.

These are my points:

```
all_points=[1,
 3,
 5,
 8,
 13,
 18,
 19,
 23,
 29,
 43,
 59,
 91,
 117,
 142,
 182,
 227,
 273,
 328,
 378,
 457,
 584,
 690,
 795,
 954,
 1121,
 1308,
 1443,
 1631.9364705363532,
 1804.9382806353701,
 1971.3305811288387,
 2127.4886735057694,
 2270.704855823829,
 2399.303500575272,
 2512.6024410490645,
 2610.7624024120405,
 2694.578574333151,
 2765.2629246948804,
 2824.250702019586,
 2873.0478944311526,
 2913.123196947984,
 2945.839893876663,
 2972.419409119482,
 2993.927684633133,
 3011.276607696681,
 3025.2343961748234,
 3036.440563806448,
 3045.42254230979,
 3052.6121505000833,
 3058.360891796115,
 3062.9535901383997,
 3066.620207163055,
 3069.5458791354763,
 3071.8793165441975,
 3073.7397557776812,
 3075.2226640042577,
 3076.4043904937034,
 3077.3459398533428,
 3078.096020916834,
 3078.6935027495365,
 3079.1693882685668,
 3079.5483971929575,
 3079.85023373867,
 3080.0906006306086,
 3080.2820094290682,
 3080.434427598801,
 3080.5557949042795,
 3080.6524353252066,
 3080.7293855074945,
 3080.7906565833773,
 3080.8394428280008,
 3080.8782879160567,
 3080.9092173743766,
 3080.9338440910306,
 3080.9534523537486,
 3080.9690647817997,
 3080.981495630228,
 3080.999273836831]
```

And then I am trying to find the max slope and inflection point using this code:

```
max_growth = np.argmax(np.abs(np.gradient(all_points)))
spl = UnivariateSpline(np.arange(len(all_points)), np.gradient(all_points), k=5)
max_idx = np.argmax(spl(np.arange(len(all_points))))
```

And then plot everything including the first and second derivative curves to check how it behaves. I also try to draw a line in the max growth rate point and in the inflection point.

```
# Plot everything for illustration
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x_forward, y_fitted_future, '--', label='fitted')
ax.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o', label='Confirmed Data')
ax.plot(spl(np.arange(len(all_points))), '-', label='Confirmed Data')
ax.plot(np.arange(len(np.gradient(all_points))), np.gradient(all_points), '-', label='Confirmed Data')
#ax.axvline(x = max_growth, linewidth=4, color='r', alpha=0.5)
ax.axvline(x = max_growth, linewidth=1, color='r', alpha=0.5)
ax.axvline(x = max_idx, linewidth=1, color='r', alpha=0.5)
ax.set_ylim([0, y_max])
```

However, the vlines are overlapping and I think my `np.gradient` and `spline` are returning the exact same derivative.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The max slope is supposed to happen exactly at the inflection point (check the second paragraph on the [definition of inflection point on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#Definition)). Isn't that what you are getting?

From the graph, I guess so, since the red line passes both at the inflection point of the logistic function and at the maximum point of its derivative (but to be sure, the example code should provide the definition of the variables `x_forward`, `y_fitted_future`, `x_data` and `y_data` used in the plot).